# About ruby on rails getting values from checkbox?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In new.html.erb

```
`<div>
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "hockeys", nil %>
<%= f.label :hockeys %>
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "cricket", nil %>
<%= f.label :cricket %>
</div>`
```

In show.html.erb

`<%@rteacher.hobby%>`

Output(If i select multiple checkbox)

```
`---""hobby"--""cricket`
```

Comment: Define "unable to fetch". What have you tried?

Comment: in my out put it displays hobby=1 or hobby =0

Comment: i want hobby = cricket or hobby = hockey

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA: Please do not post code as comments. instead, edit your original question to add more content.

Comment: plz help me i am new in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where are your values?**

Your checkbox needs to have a value associated with it, otherwise Rails won't know what data to feed to the controller & db. Here's a definition:

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")
```

[API reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box)

I'd do something like this:

```
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:class => "myclass", :style => "mystyle"}, "hockeys" %>
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:class => "myclass", :style => "mystyle"}, "cricket" %>
```

**Update**

To give multiple values, you should use the [`:multiple`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box#1001-Sending-array-parameters) option:

```
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "hockeys", nil %>
<%= f.check_box :hobby, {:multiple => "true"}, "cricket", nil %>
```

Comment: How to get multiple value from checkbox using your code I'am getting any one value out of three option plz help me asap

Comment: I'll change the code for you

Comment: sorry sir Rick Peck I'm still not getting the answer, my output using your above updated code is again 1 or 0, I'm still unable to fetch the multiple value from the checkbox

Comment: Okay, sorry I got the syntax wrong. I have just updated for you :)

Comment: thank you sir but, in the display  i am getting weird out put such as  Hobby = -- -""-hpckey-""-cricket and in the show option i have writter      `<%=@rstuds.hobby%>`